# Jquery Mobile dialog close not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Hi I have a function like below,

```
$("#OkButton").click(function(e){
    $("#sampleDlg").dialog('close');
        //Ajax call
    $("#sampleDlg").dialog('open');
});
```

On clicking ok button i want the dialog to get closed and open a new dialog with same dialogID after completion of AJAX call. Right now the close event is triggered only after the completion of Click function hence it closes both the dialogs.
Please assist me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which JQM version are you using?

Comment: @Omar Thank you for your reply.In my project they wrote a wrapper on the top of the dialog.That's the problem after a day spent i found that and fixed the bug.Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the async nature of AJAX requests you need to open the next dialog within the callback handler of `$.ajax`:

```
$("#OkButton").click(function(e){
    $("#sampleDlg").dialog('close');
    $.ajax({
        url: '.foo.html',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sampleDlg").dialog('open');
        }  
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments.I already tried i am able to open  second dialogue.But i am not able to close the first dialog.At the end of callback only close event is triggered so both the dialogue gets closed.

Comment: Here the issue is with JqueryMobile dialogue close event i don't know why it doesn't happen at the end of the statement.The close event is triggered only at the end of the block.